# Decision rule for Bayesian variable selection

Tags: feature-selection, hierarchical-bayesian, threshold

I'm fitting a spike-and-slab regression model to sparse data and obtaining posterior probabilities of association (PPA). I now would like to 'declare' associations based on the latter. I'm concerned about finding a reasonable choice of threshold on these PPAs. I know that people often use a 0.5 threshold (which is known to be optimal for prediction problems). Another option would be to make the selection after associating Bayesian FDR to the PPAs.

I'm wondering whether we could do something else, which would exploit the fact that in very sparse settings, the empirical distribution of the PPAs will typically be bimodal, with a large bulk around 0. Is there some work about using mixture distributions to effectively declare associations?

Alternatively, I guess one could run a permutation analysis by altering the labels of the response, and obtaining a collection of `null'
$PPA_j^{(t)}, j = 1, \ldots, p, t = 1, \ldots, T,$
(for a problem with $p$ candidate covariates and $T$ permutations). Then  empirical p-values for each covariate $j$ could be obtained as
$$\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t= 1}^T \mathbb{1}(PPA_j^{(t)} > PPA_j)\,.$$
I guess this would work but one would have to perform a quite large number of permutations (each time fitting the model on all $p$ covariates) which can be computationally expensive in high-dimensional Bayesian settings.
on the other hand, it would be quite tempting to use instead
$$\frac{1}{T p} \sum_{t= 1}^T \sum_{k = 1}^p \mathbb{1}(PPA_k^{(t)} > PPA_j)\,,$$
which would probably require much less permutations... I'm not sure this would be correct though, since the $p$ $PPA_j^{(t)}$ from a given permuted instance $t$ are not independent.

I would be grateful to have your opinions on these concerns. What would you do? Is there some useful literature you could refer me to?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Would anybody have an input on this please?